# How to pass custom parameters when creating docker swarm service?

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, docker-swarm

I am new to docker and docker swarm and started dockerizing several services and am trying to get them running as docker swarm services. I ran into a road block with the linuxserver/ffmpeg image:

1. it uses a --device parameter which is not implemented in create service
2. it expects several custom parameters to pass them to the ffmpeg encoder

From my research up to now I assume that passing parameters is not implemented in docker create service, but maybe you can think of a workaround? (unfortunately the image does not process environment variables, or at least they are not documented)

This is how I start dockerized ffmpeg (working fine in standalone mode):

docker run -d /
--network="host" /
--device=/dev/video0:/dev/video0  / ### error: unknow flag 
--name ffmpeg_streamer /
--restart always -it /
-v $(pwd)/video:/video /
linuxserver/ffmpeg    / ###  custom parameters below here 
-stream_loop /
-1 -re -nostdin /
-i "/video/test.avi" /
-f pulse /
-vcodec libx264 /
-preset:v veryfast /
-b:v 400k /
-f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/streamkey

Many thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this docker-compose file

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  ffmpeg_streamer:
    image: 'linuxserver/ffmpeg'
    restart: always
    devices:
      - "/dev/video0:/dev/video0" #make sure the folde /dev/video0 exist in your host
    command: ["-stream_loop", "-1", "-re", "-nostdin", "-i" ,"/video/test.avi", "-f", "pulse", "-vcodec", "libx264", "-preset:v", "veryfast", "-b:v", "400k", "-f", "flv", "rtmp://localhost:1935/live/streamkey"]
    network_mode: host
    volumes:
      - './video:/video'
```

you can run it using this command: `docker-compos up -d`

Comment: many thanks. I tried as you suggested, ffmpeg starts but has difficulties parsing the arguments and I get the following:  

Unrecognized option '-path.rootfs=/host'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found  

If I remove the path option, it seems to be able to process "-stream_loop -1 -r -nostdin" but  the other options fail:  

Unrecognized option 'i "/video/test.avi" '.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found  

(same with any of the other options when changing their order. Double dashes I tried as well (Unrecognized option '-i /video/test.avi'))

Comment: the option '-path.rootfs=/host' was a mistake I removed it.

Comment: I made some changes, can you test now?

Comment: same as before: Unrecognized option 'i /video/test.avi '.
ffmpeg_streamer_1  | Error splitting the argument list: Option not found

Comment: let's try it with an array, because apparently ffmpeg is not able to split argument in a string with whitespaces

Comment: yesss, Kamèl, this was it. Many thanks for guiding me through this.  I had to break up the first part until the -i option as well:  command: ["-stream_loop", "-1", "-re",  "-nostdin", "-i" ,"/video/test.avi", "-f", "pulse", "-vcodec", "libx264", "-preset:v", "veryfast", "-b:v", "400k", "-f", "flv", "rtmp://localhost:1935/live/streamkey"]